# Scala: if-else expression as left operand, operation is performed only if condition evaluates to false?

Tags: scala

Like the following example:

```
scala> if (true) { 1 } else { 2 } + 3
val res1: Int = 1

scala> if (false) { 1 } else { 2 } + 3
val res2: Int = 5
```

It seems as if the curly braces are ignored. Wrapping the if-else expression with parentheses seems to work as expected.

```
scala> (if (true) { 1 } else { 2 }) + 3
val res3: Int = 4
```

This appears super unintuitive to me. Can someone please help me understand this?

Comment: if expression has lower precedence than plus operator so plus is done first. Curly braces in Scala is not bound with if expression. It’s just a way to group statements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intuition is that braces simply create a block *expression* that can be part of a larger expression. They are not part of the `if` *statement*.

The general form of `if` is

```
if (<test>) <expression> else <expression>
```

In the question the code after the `else` is a simple expression:

```
{ 2 } + 3
```

`+` has a higher precedence than `if/else` so it is parsed as

```
if (<test>) { 1 } else ({ 2 } + 3)
```

rather than

```
(if (<test>) { 1 } else { 2 }) + 3
```